# Mysql - .log file with no name

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know why I am seeing a .log file in my MySQL directory that has no name (see screenshot below)? I'm on a windows 2012 R2 server, MySQL 5.7.16-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL). The size seems to get quite large and it appears to be a binary file. Restarting the server empties the file. But does not delete it.

[image]

Comment: What's the server's hostname?

Comment: Any custom logging configuration?

Comment: @FrankerZ that's the weird thing. the hostname does appear for the -slow.log and .err log.

Comment: @MattClark No, there is no custom logging. This is an out of the box config.